# How to add lots of overlay to MKMapView in background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, mkmapview

I have a tableView , each cell in table view has a MKMapView as a subView ,and when i construct a cell , i need to add lot of overlay to the map view (based on gps points) . now , i do all the work in main thread , but when the tableview is scrolling , because there is alot of calculation and addOverlay , so the performance is too bad , How to improve this kind of problem?thex

Comment: Use GCD for load map in cell.

Comment: Yup, do not load data into your cells on the mainthread. You should use a background thread to do the loading of the data, the calculations and filling of the cells (/overlay). To prevent the user from wondering what is going on, you should use placeholders for each bit of information that needs to be loaded.

Comment: Hi, now ,i use gcd for creating cells ,but i found i have to put the MapKit API : addOverlays to main thread ,otherwise , app will crash, and because i got several hundred overlays to add(i use addOverlays NOT addOverlay already) in each cell , so the scrolling is still very lag , and the logs shows that ,when i add 300 overlays is need about 1.5 second to execute the [mapView addOverlays:overlays], can i short the time addOverlays cost?

Comment: and in debugging ,i found [mapView addOverlays:overlays] will call mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay hundred times,i thinks these may cause the problem , but how to do with it ?

Comment: @ximmyxiao currently, I am also facing same issue for loading thousands of overlays to mapview, what is the solution you found for this, can you share here, it would help for us also. Thanks!

Comment: Please check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49360012/mapview-getting-freezing-for-few-seconds-while-loading-thousands-of-data-and-zoo I am also facing same kind issue, can you please post the answer if you would found for your issue?