# MapView getting freezing for few seconds while loading thousands of data and zoom-in time in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, overlay, geoswift

I am developing `Mapview` in swift language. For, that I am loading geojson file into my mapview, its loading successfully. I am loading with `GEOSwift` library. Its working fine, but, what happening, While loading data, the mapview getting freeze/stuck for few seconds in UI, then later showing data. Even while Zooming time also freezing the UI few seconds.

I am loading `LineString` type data with coordinates around 7000 data.

Even I am doing parsing the data in background thread only.

I have two 3 tabs for loading different data in my map with 3 `geojson`

files. Even while switching one data to another data, its getting freezing.

In debugging are following error printing while zoomin/zoomout the mapview.

```
 [VKDefault] Tile 11720.7599.14 (128) in current unloaded state for 0.01 seconds - Raster Overlays Above Labels - Failed to decode (terminal) (0.01 sec)
```

My code is follows.

```
@IBAction func mapDataAction(_ sender: Any) {
        let overlays = mapView.overlays
        mapView.removeOverlays(overlays)

        self.mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)


        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            if let geoJSONURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: “LineString”, withExtension: "geojson") {
                do {
                    var overlays = [MKPolyline]()
                    let features = try Features.fromGeoJSON(geoJSONURL)
                    for item in features! {
                        if  let item = item.geometries![0] as? LineString {
                            let polyLine = item.mapShape() as! MKPolyline
                            overlays.append(polyLine)
                        }
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        // add overlays to map
                        self.mapView.addOverlays(overlays)
                    }

                } catch {
                    //handle error
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And one time app gets crashed with following message thrown in console.

```
Terminated due to memory issue
```

And its taking huge memory from cpu of device.

[image]

While scrolling the mapview or zoomin/zoomout its calling always the delegate method, this making freezing the mapview.

```
public func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    if let polyline = overlay as? MKPolyline {
        let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: polyline)
        //renderer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
        renderer.lineWidth = 5
         print("MKPolylineRenderer delegate calling")
        return renderer
    }


    return MKOverlayRenderer(overlay: overlay)

 //   fatalError("Unexpected overlay type")
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: did you check what exactly takes time here? this parsing does not look like background thread

Comment: its printing this in debugging area [VKDefault] Tile 11720.7599.14 (128) in current unloaded state for 0.01 seconds - Raster Overlays Above Labels - Failed to decode (terminal) (0.01 sec)

Comment: @Lu_ any suggestions on this?

Comment: remove `do {` and use `let features = try! Features.fromGeoJSON(geoJSONURL)`

Comment: Then how to do this exercise if we remove that line?

Comment: what exercise? what are you talking about? it just make your code slow

Comment: If I remove do { its throwing error at         DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

Comment: oh god, reamove everything that you added with `do {` there is also `catch` did you write that code?

Comment: @Lu_ I did that only, removed do { and then catch {

Comment: Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '() throws -> ()' to non-throwing function type '@convention(block) () -> Void' throwing this error  pls check this https://www.pastiebin.com/5ab1fe40c1613

Comment: i dont know what error is

Comment: use it like i said in comment `try!`

Comment: its loading, will tell the result

Comment: While zooming/zoomout its getting freezing and the mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay delegate method calling

Comment: do you load all the data again when zooming?

Comment: nope, creating polylione happening in that delegate method

Comment: so you need to measure everything what are you doing and then you will know what to improve

Comment: I am already doing parsing, then adding the data to mapview, that its, then why its happening freezing?

Comment: Can you help me, while zoomin/zoomout why always  this delegate methods calls?   public func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {

Comment: because it needs to be called, if you use that it should be called when rendering

Comment: and you still didnt show which line exactly is taking time and freezing app

Comment: I already posted the delegate method is calling while zooming/zoomout the mapview, that one only making freeze the app.

Comment: I added delegate method too, please check once @Lu_

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167240/discussion-between-anilkumar-ios-developer-and-lu).

Comment: @Lu_ did you checked my updated question?

Comment: yes, it looks like whole app design is just bad and map is unreadable

Comment: so, no solution for this?

Comment: i dont know the code and any of your measurements if it really is this delegate that is causing the problem

Comment: Yes, this delegate method calling frequently, thats why app makes freezing due to heavy data.